# Always On High Availability join command not supported by this edition

Tags: sql-server

I have error when trying to configure Always On High Availability in SQL Server 2016.

The error stated that:

> The specified command is invalid because the Always On Availability Groups join availability group features is not supported by this edition of SQL Server.

But both primary and secondary replica use same version.

[image]

It is because of clustering problem or because of SQL Server version?

Comment: Off-topic - belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). Surely someone will ask you there about which edition you are using. It is important to understand the difference between version and edition - features vary by [edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: That's right.I checked the SQL Server version on both server and found there are match.But different edition that cause the problem.I just updated my answer. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research,i found a way to check the current edition of SQL Server by using SQL script.The error message was right. Both server using different edition of SQL Server. One server is using Developer Edition while the other one use Standard Edition.

Can check the script here:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/determining-the-version-dbc1c53a